# How to correct Generic sort code to sort nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, sorting, nullable

We've been using this method for sorting a generic List<>.  Recently, we noticed incorrect results when the target property in T was a nullable type (decimal?).  Any ideas how to correct?

```
public void SortList<T>(List<T> dataSource, string fieldName, SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName);
    Comparison<T> compare = delegate(T a, T b)
    {
        bool asc = sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending;
        object valueA = asc ? propInfo.GetValue(a, null) : propInfo.GetValue(b, null);
        object valueB = asc ? propInfo.GetValue(b, null) : propInfo.GetValue(a, null);

        return valueA is IComparable ? ((IComparable)valueA).CompareTo(valueB) : 0;
    };
    dataSource.Sort(compare);
}
```

Above code from Phil Hustead's article, "Sorting Generic Lists and IEnumerables by Object Property Name"
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27851/Sorting-Generic-Lists-and-IEnumerables-by-Object-P

For instance, for my *Employee* objects with nullable decimal property *Hours*.

The nullable hours
**107, null, 8, 152, 64, null** 
sorts to
**8, null, 64, null, 107, 152**.

The nulls should sort, I think, to the beginning or end of the list.

Comment: Please provide some sample input that you find problematic with the both actual result and the result you would want instead. And why would you even use your method when dealing with `List<decimal?>` - just use List's `Sort` method and a default comparer will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your method to

```
public static void SortList<T>(List<T> dataSource, string fieldName, SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(fieldName);
    Comparison<T> compare = delegate(T a, T b)
    {
        bool asc = sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending;
        object valueA = asc ? propInfo.GetValue(a, null) : propInfo.GetValue(b, null);
        object valueB = asc ? propInfo.GetValue(b, null) : propInfo.GetValue(a, null);

        if(valueA == null)
        {
            if(valueB == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return asc ? -1 : 1;
            }
        }
        if(valueB == null)
        {
            return asc ? 1 : -1;
        }

        return valueA is IComparable ? ((IComparable)valueA).CompareTo(valueB) : 0;
    };
    dataSource.Sort(compare);
}
```

Main issue is that you are checking `valueA` for `IComparable` only, and if `valueA == null` - comparison returns that objects are equal, no matter what is in `valueB`. When nullable value is boxed (and this is exactly what is happening here) it is represented by an actual value or `null`.

Comment: When calling this method with "Value" (which is only property name I can think of that would make sense when using this with `decimal?`) as `fieldName`, you'll get a `TargetException`.

Comment: Yes, but the question is a bit confusing. OP is sorting objects with a nullable property, not a list with `decimal?` (`T` is `Employee`, `fieldName` is `Hours` and `Hours` is `decimal?`)

Comment: Aha, didn't notice the OP's edit. I thought that OP really wanted to sort a `decimal?`List.

Answer (score 0):

The above (final) example supporting nullable values works great for my List, but only in certain scenarios. My CustomType contains four fields, two of which are string types and two of which are DateTime? (nullable) types.

When I sort on either of the string values, it works great. However, when I sort on either of the nullable DateTime? values, it sorts the one DateTime? value properly, but it "loses" the info for the string values!

I'm left with a List sorted by the specified DateTime? value, and still containing the other DateTime? value, but emptied-out string values?

Any ideas here?